# Unable to find parts in workspace with localscript

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm fairly new to Roblox studio and am in the process of making a PC building game. I'm currently trying to make it so when a player steps on a "BuyBlock" they get an attribute added for that part. Using this code:

```
local list = game.Workspace.Store.GPU.BuyBlocks:GetDescendants()

while true do
    for index=1, #list  do
        if list[index] then
            
            list[index].Touched:Connect(function()
                Touched(list[index])
                
            end)
        end
    end
    wait(1)
end
```

Essentially, the code iterates through each "BuyBlock" until one is touched and then calls a function to change the players attribute to that part. This part worked as a normal script in the workspace however i realised it would need to be a LocalScript to change the players attribute and so i did, adding the rest of the code and moving to StarterPlayerScripts:

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

local function Touched(part) -- called whenever one of the parts are touched

    player:SetAttribute("GPU", part)
end
```

Im assuming LocalScripts can't search through the workspace however i can't think of how to split the two pieces of code into Local and non-Local scripts. Any suggestions or explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to confirm first that all the parts have loaded in. It might just be the replication time taking too long, registering the Touched events on only a few parts that *have* loaded in.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a separate function then make sure to use WaitForChild to reference it before using it in an argument.
Probably not the best way to go around it, but it works.

greenPart = game.Workspace:WaitForChild("Green Part")

local function Touched(part)
player:SetAttribute("GPU", part)
end

Touched(greenPart)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).